# Kali Linux terminal command trouble

Tags: terminal

Hi I am a new user of Kali linux. I have a trouble here. In the terminal no command is working. even if i put "ipconfig" it says bash: ipconfig: command not found.

can anybody please tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: What about `printenv PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux it is not `ipconfig`, its `ifconfig`.

Try few commands like `mkdir test` `ls -l` `who` `touch test.txt`

Comment: or `ip`: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/846486-replacing-ifconfig-with-ip